# Position a subview on the edge of a circular shaped view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, position

I'm trying to create a profile picture view that looks like the mock-up below. It has a small green dot to denote the user's online status.

[image]

I'm creating the view programmatically so I can reuse it. Below is my code so far.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ProfileView: UIView {

    fileprivate var imageView: UIImageView!
    fileprivate var onlineStatusView: UIView!
    fileprivate var onlineStatusDotView: UIView!


    @IBInspectable
    var image: UIImage? {
        get { return imageView.image }
        set { imageView.image = newValue }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shouldShowStatusDot: Bool = true


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        backgroundColor = .clear

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: bounds)
        imageView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height / 2
        addSubview(imageView)

        onlineStatusView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (bounds.height / 5), height: (bounds.height / 5)))
        onlineStatusView.backgroundColor = .white
        onlineStatusView.clipsToBounds = true
        onlineStatusView.layer.cornerRadius = onlineStatusView.frame.height / 2
        addSubview(onlineStatusView)

        onlineStatusDotView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (onlineStatusView.bounds.height / 1.3), height: (onlineStatusView.bounds.height / 1.3)))
        onlineStatusDotView.center = onlineStatusView.center
        onlineStatusDotView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.17, green: 0.71, blue: 0.45, alpha: 1.0)
        onlineStatusDotView.clipsToBounds = true
        onlineStatusDotView.layer.cornerRadius = onlineStatusDotView.frame.height / 2
        onlineStatusView.addSubview(onlineStatusDotView)
    }
}
```

[image]

What has me lost is how to pin the green dot view on the *circular* edge of the top right corner of the image view. Obviously the view's frame isn't circular so I can't figure out what auto layout constraints to use in this case. And I don't want to hardcode the values either because it has to move depending on the size of the image view.

What auto layout constraints do I have to set to get it to the right position?

I uploaded a [demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/su7xj0cnwohzffw/ReusableProfileView.zip?dl=0) here as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To place the small green circle in the upper right corner of the big circle:

1. Make the small circle a subview of the big circle.
2. Add a constraint with the `.centerX` of the small circle equal to the `.trailing` of the big circle with a `multiplier` of `0.8536`.
3. Add a constraint with the `.centerY` of the small circle equal to the `.bottom` of the big circle with a `multiplier` of `0.1464`.

**Note:** The two `multiplier`s were computed using *Trigonometry* by looking at the unit circle and computing the ratios: `(distance from top of square containing unit circle)/(height of unit circle)` and `(distance from left edge of square containing unit circle)/(width of unit circle)`.  In the sample code below, I have provided a `func` called `computeMultipliers(angle:)` which computes the multipliers for any `angle` in degrees.  Avoid angles exactly `90` and `180` because that can create multipliers of `0` which *Auto Layout* does not like.

---

Here is standalone example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var bigCircle: UIView!
    var littleCircle: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        bigCircle = UIView()
        bigCircle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bigCircle.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(bigCircle)
        
        bigCircle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240).isActive = true
        bigCircle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240).isActive = true
        
        littleCircle = UIView()
        littleCircle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        littleCircle.backgroundColor = .green
        bigCircle.addSubview(littleCircle)

        bigCircle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bigCircle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        littleCircle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        littleCircle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        
        let (hMult, vMult) = computeMultipliers(angle: 45)
        
        // position the little green circle using a multiplier on the right and bottom
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: littleCircle!, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigCircle!, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: hMult, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: littleCircle!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigCircle!, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: vMult, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        bigCircle.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * bigCircle.frame.height
        
        littleCircle.layoutIfNeeded()
        littleCircle.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * littleCircle.frame.height
    }

    func computeMultipliers(angle: CGFloat) -> (CGFloat, CGFloat) {
        let radians = angle * .pi / 180
        
        let h = (1.0 + cos(radians)) / 2
        let v = (1.0 - sin(radians)) / 2
        
        return (h, v)
    }
}
```

---

[image: image of sample code running in the simulator]

---

Here is a modified version of your code.  I added constraints to set the size of the small circle and moved the code which sets the `cornerRadius` to `layoutSubviews()`:

```
class ProfilePictureView: UIView {
    var bigCircle: UIView!
    var borderCircle: UIView!
    var littleCircle: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }
    
    private func initialize() {
        bigCircle = UIView(frame: bounds)
        bigCircle.backgroundColor = .red
        addSubview(bigCircle)
        
        borderCircle = UIView()
        borderCircle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        borderCircle.backgroundColor = .white
        bigCircle.addSubview(borderCircle)
        
        borderCircle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bigCircle.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true
        borderCircle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bigCircle.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true
        
        littleCircle = UIView()
        littleCircle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        littleCircle.backgroundColor = .green
        borderCircle.addSubview(littleCircle)
        
        littleCircle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderCircle.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/1.3).isActive = true
        littleCircle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderCircle.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/1.3).isActive = true
        littleCircle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderCircle.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        littleCircle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: borderCircle.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        let (hMult, vMult) = computeMultipliers(angle: 45)
        
        // position the border circle using a multiplier on the right and bottom
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: borderCircle!, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigCircle!, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: hMult, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: borderCircle!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigCircle!, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: vMult, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        bigCircle.layer.cornerRadius = bigCircle.frame.height / 2
        borderCircle.layoutIfNeeded()
        borderCircle.layer.cornerRadius = borderCircle.frame.height / 2
        littleCircle.layoutIfNeeded()
        littleCircle.layer.cornerRadius = littleCircle.frame.height / 2
    }
    
    private func computeMultipliers(angle: CGFloat) -> (CGFloat, CGFloat) {
        let radians = angle * .pi / 180
        
        let h = (1.0 + cos(radians)) / 2
        let v = (1.0 - sin(radians)) / 2
        
        return (h, v)
    }
}
```

---

[image: second image with white border]

---

#### Explanation of the math behind `computeMultipliers(angle:)`

The idea of `computeMultipliers(angle:)` is that is should compute a multiplier for the *horizontal constraint* and a multiplier for the *vertical constraint*.  These values are a proportion and will range from `0` to `1` where `0` is the *top* of the circle for the vertical constraint and `0` is the *left* edge of the circle for the horizontal constraint.  Likewise, `1` is the *bottom* of the circle for the vertical constraint and `1` is the *right* edge of the circle for the horizontal constraint.

The multipliers are computed by looking at [*the unit circle*](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html) in Trigonometry.  The unit circle is a circle of radius `1` centered at `(0, 0)` on the coordinate system.  The nice thing about the unit circle (by definition) is that the point on the circle where a line (starting at the origin) intersects the circle is `(cos(angle), sin(angle))` where the angle is measured starting at positive `x-axis` going counter-clockwise to the line that intersects the circle.  Note the the width and height of the unit circle are each `2`.

`sin(angle)` and `cos(angle)` each vary from `-1` to `1`.

The equation:

```
1 + cos(angle)
```

will vary from `0` to `2` depending on the angle.  Since we're looking for a value from `0` to `1`, we divide this by `2`:

```
// compute the horizontal multiplier based upon the angle
let h = (1.0 + cos(radians)) / 2
```

In the vertical direction, we first note the coordinate system is flipped from the mathematical sense.  In iOS, `y` grows in the downward direction, but in mathematics, `y` grows in the upward direction.  To account for this, the vertical calculation uses minus `-` instead of `+`:

```
1 - sin(angle)
```

Again, since `sin` varies from `-1` to `1`, this calculation will be from `0` to `2`, so we divide by `2`:

```
// compute the vertical multiplier based upon the angle
let h = (1.0 - sin(radians)) / 2
```

This gives us the desired result.  When the angle is `90` degrees (or `.pi/2` radians), `sin` is `1`, so the vertical multiplier will be `0`.  When the angle is `270` degrees (or `3*.pi/2` radians), `sin` is `-1` and the vertical multiplier will be `1`.

*Why use radians?*  Radians are intuitive once you understand what they are.  They are just the length of arc along the circumference of the unit circle.  The formula for the circumference of a circle is `circumference = 2 * .pi * radius`, so for the unit circle, the circumference is `2 * .pi`.  So `360` degrees is `2 * .pi` radians.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm trying to incorporate the calculation part to my reusable view. So I removed the hardcoded height, width constraints and commented out `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for `bigCircle` and `littleCircle` views. Because of that now the green dot positioning constraints aren't getting applied it seems. How should I allow the user set the dimension constraints but set the positioning constraints myself both? Here is my [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5j02pv3vh5wvka/ReusableProfilePictureView.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Leave the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for the small circle. You are proving all 4 constraints for that view.

Comment: The small circle should have equal width constraint with big circle with a multiplier 0.2  and an equal width to its own height with multiplier 1.

Comment: It’s still early here. I’ll be able to look at your code in about 1.5 hours.

Comment: It's okay. No hurry :) I'll try to follow what you've said in your comments in the meantime.

Comment: I added another update.  The green circle now has a white border.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is perfect. One question. Is there a specific reason why setting `cornerRadius` is done inside the `layoutSubviews` method? I also modified the code a little bit so that the `borderCircle` will dynamically have the superview's background color instead of hardcoding it. And I noticed that setting `borderCircle.backgroundColor = superview?.backgroundColor` it inside the `initialize` method did not work either. I had to move it to `layoutSubviews` in order to get it to work.

Comment: The frame of the views isn't established until *Auto Layout* runs.  `layoutSubviews()` happens at *Auto Layout* time, so you need to wait until the frame is established to set the cornerRadius.  The reason you had to delay your background color was that the view hasn't been added to the view hierarchy at the time it is created.  Couldn't you accomplish the same thing by making the border color `.clear`?

Comment: No, I tried that but since the `borderCircle` is a subview of the `bigCircle`, setting the background color of it to `.clear` lets the background color of the `bigCircle` to show through. So it looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/GEj00x9.jpg). I wanted something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/zIR1QCx.jpg).

Comment: Right. That makes sense.

Comment: great answer but what does h and v respresent

Comment: `h` is the **h**orizontal multiplier, `v` is the **v**ertical multiplier.

Comment: do you mind telling me what these trigonometry equations are called I'm really intrested in studying the algorithm more

Comment: do you maybe have a link to material I might read about these trigonometry equations and how they relate to the calculation of mutlipliers

Comment: I created this "algorithm" with my own knowledge of trigonometry and the unit circle.  This link about [the unit circle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Erent, I updated the answer with a detailed explanation of the calculation of the two multipliers.

Comment: @vacawama Nice result and explanation, could you please elaborate more on why you added the smallCircle to bigCircle instead of it's parents? and why adding the smallCircle to the superView will result in having it outside the edge if the bigCircle.

Comment: @Scar, adding the small circle to the big circle gives it a coordinate system relative to the big circle. The origin of the the small circle’s coordinate system will be the upper left corner of the big circle’s frame. This is necessary for the small circle to stick with the big circle no matter where it goes because this technique sets the absolute x and y coordinates for the small circle and we need those to be in the coordinate system that is relative to the big circle.

Comment: @vacawama thanks for the explanation, I think I have to do some research and fix and issue where the smallCircle is cut of if the bigCircle `clipsToBounds` is true

Comment: @Scar. Try this. Use a dummy invisible view as a placeholder for the small circle. Make it a subview of the big circle. Add the real small circle to the superview and add constraints to set its horizontal and vertical centers to the center of the dummy view.

Comment: Is there a way to re-write this in a way that we can use `90` and `180` angles safely without something like `hMult = hMult == 0 ? 0.0001 : hMult`?

Comment: @zakdances, 90 and 180 do need special handling. The 0.0001 workaround while ugly does avoid the problem.  If you don’t want to do that, then you can check for the zero multiplier and then create a constraint that doesn’t use the multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

Change your initialize function with the following:
You can see the result in the given image link...

```
  private func initialize() {
    backgroundColor = .clear

    imageView = UIImageView(frame: bounds)
    imageView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height / 2
    addSubview(imageView)

    onlineStatusView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (bounds.height / 5), height: (bounds.height / 5)))
    onlineStatusView.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 7, y: bounds.height / 7)
    onlineStatusView.backgroundColor = .white
    onlineStatusView.clipsToBounds = true
    onlineStatusView.layer.cornerRadius = onlineStatusView.frame.height / 2
    addSubview(onlineStatusView)

    onlineStatusDotView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (onlineStatusView.bounds.height / 1.3), height: (onlineStatusView.bounds.height / 1.3)))
      onlineStatusDotView.center = CGPoint(x: onlineStatusView.frame.width / 2, y: onlineStatusView.frame.height / 2)
    onlineStatusDotView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.17, green: 0.71, blue: 0.45, alpha: 1.0)
    onlineStatusDotView.clipsToBounds = true
    onlineStatusDotView.layer.cornerRadius = onlineStatusDotView.frame.height / 2
    onlineStatusView.addSubview(onlineStatusDotView)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the green dot has to be on the top right corner. And I don't want to hardcode the positioning values because if the size of the imageview changes, the green dot has to move too.

Comment: You can use any size box for the image. It will work as you can see the above attached image is of size 250x250 and for moving green dot position to right side, let me try

Comment: Change the line with this :
onlineStatusView.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width - bounds.width / 7, y: bounds.height / 7)