# How to position a button over a rounded imageview?

Tags: ios, swift

How to position a button over a rounded imageview using autolaout?

Please check the image below

[image]

Currently I'm using some hard coded value. But If the image view width increases based on device, the button isn't in correct position

Comment: Show your current relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy I use storyboard

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041557/1630618

Comment: @vacawama Thanks.That doesn't come up in search

Comment: Yeah, SO searching is not very good.  I found it because I wrote it and remembered that I had answered a similar question.  Your "duplicate" question might lead someone else to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use autolayout from your Xib file then make 4 constraints for the edit button like this:

- Fix width and height for the button
- Constraint the trailing of the button equal to the image
- Constraint the bottom of the button equal to the image