# How to put one UIImage ontop of another with specific dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

[image]

I have a button on which I want to add a round image and also add another small image with white border at the bottom corner of the main image. The small image has to have its center connecting to one of the main circular image's circle path as shown in the image.

My current problem is getting the small image to have its center be a point on the larger image.

I have tried to use a little bit of geometry to get the small circle in the position I want however when the button is really small the math breaks.

```swift
public class CustomButton: UIButton {

    fileprivate let icon: UIImageView = {

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .center
        imageView.image = UIColor.green.image(CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))

        return imageView
    }()

    public class func button() -> CustomButton {

        let button = CustomButton(type: .system)

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                left: 0,
                                                bottom: 0,
                                                right: 0)

        let image = UIColor.lightGray.image(CGSize(width: 64, height: 64))
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return button
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupView() {

        icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18.0).isActive = true
        icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18.0).isActive = true

        self.addSubview(icon)
        icon.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        icon.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let iconRadius = 9
        let mainImageRadius = self.bounds.width/2

        self.roundView(view: self.imageView!, radius: mainImageRadius, borderWith: 0, borderColor: UIColor.clear)
        self.roundView(view: icon, radius: CGFloat(iconRadius), borderWith: CGFloat(2), borderColor: UIColor.white)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    func roundView(view: UIView, radius: CGFloat, borderWith: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor) {
        // Add rounded corners
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = view.bounds
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.allCorners], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)).cgPath
        view.layer.mask = maskLayer

        // Add border
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path // Reuse the Bezier path
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWith
        borderLayer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }

}
```

I would like to create a button that looks like the one on the image one that is reusable and adjusts the icon's size to match button size.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57037935/1630618) and its accepted answer.